# Optimal way to convert start/stop times into a dataframe for counting concurrency

Tags: r

I have 5 million+ rows of appointment data (start/stop times) that I am looking to convert to 15 minute blocks to use for demand forecasting and scheduling.

Example:

```
Start time: 9:30

Stop time: 10:10
```

I am looking to populate columns `9:30-9:44`, `9:45-9:59`, `10:00-10:14`  each with a one and the other 93 columns would have a zero for that particular row.

Thanks.

Comment: Just realized I can do this with a join in a DB that has the time in 15 minute increments.  INNER JOIN #Data DB ON  SLOT.SlotStartDateTime >=LowerBound AND SLOT.SlotStartDateTime < UpperBound

Comment: you could use ```lubridate``` to find the overlaps between your appointments and the time blocks. If you post a small example (maybe via ```dput(head(df))```) I can write the code in more detail.

Comment: Here's the output of dput ->  structure(list(start = structure(c(1539764520, 1539763920, 1539765180, 
1539765180, 1539764400, 1539764400), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = ""), stop = structure(c(1539769320, 1539777420, 1539803940, 
1539803940, 1539770700, 1539770700), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = "")), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

Answer (score 0):

```
> dput <- structure(
+     list(
+         start = structure(c(1539764520, 1539763920, 1539765180, 1539765180, 1539764400, 1539764400), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt" ), tzone = ""), 
+         stop = structure(c(1539769320, 1539777420, 1539803940, 1539803940, 1539770700, 1539770700), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt" ), tzone = "")), 
+     row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
> dput
                start                stop
1 2018-10-17 17:22:00 2018-10-17 18:42:00
2 2018-10-17 17:12:00 2018-10-17 20:57:00
3 2018-10-17 17:33:00 2018-10-18 04:19:00
4 2018-10-17 17:33:00 2018-10-18 04:19:00
5 2018-10-17 17:20:00 2018-10-17 19:05:00
6 2018-10-17 17:20:00 2018-10-17 19:05:00
```

Refer to below, you can change to `ceiling_date` or `floor_date` as well :

```
> dput %>% mutate_all(round_date, '15 mins')
                start                stop
1 2018-10-17 17:15:00 2018-10-17 18:45:00
2 2018-10-17 17:15:00 2018-10-17 21:00:00
3 2018-10-17 17:30:00 2018-10-18 04:15:00
4 2018-10-17 17:30:00 2018-10-18 04:15:00
5 2018-10-17 17:15:00 2018-10-17 19:00:00
6 2018-10-17 17:15:00 2018-10-17 19:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this might work. Your data is called df here. This approach hinges on the use of lubridate's `int_overlaps` function, that can detect whether there is an overlap between the appointments and the intervals (blocks) you specify.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

no_intervals <- 95  #number of intervals
intervals_start <- ymd_hms("2018-10-17 10:00:00")
intervals_width <- 15 #in minutes


#define intervals for the blocks you want to populate
blocks <- lapply(1:no_intervals, function(shift){
  interval((intervals_start + (shift-1) * minutes(intervals_width)), 
           (intervals_start + (shift)   * minutes(intervals_width)))}) %>% 
  `names<-`(paste0("int", 1 : no_intervals))

#add the overlaps of the appointments with the blocks to the df
res<- df %>% 
  mutate(appointment = interval(ymd_hms(df$start), ymd_hms(df$stop))) %>% 
  cbind(as.data.frame(lapply(blocks, int_overlaps, .$appointment))) %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(matches("^int")), as.numeric) #convert booleans to 0/1
```